# Addition sum for JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 classes with the names of:
.amount1
.amount2
.amount3

```
<td><input class="amount1" id="input_a" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
<td><input class="amount2" id="input_a_ans" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
<td><input class="amount3" id="input_a_year" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>
```

There are 20 of each. I've been trying to figure out how to get each class' total information added together and displayed in an input (class input_week). The JS I have tried is this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".amount1").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        $(".amount1").each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        $("#input_week").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

I then figured if this worked, which it doesn't, I could repeat this same code and change the class that needs to be added together and have the other class' information displayed in another input input_fort and so forth. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, this isn't a place to get people to write code for you. At least attempt getting it to work yourself and then ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: You're right. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pulling data that is pre-populated and then edited, I would suggest loading the totals before displaying the information in the page using JS. Then having on-clicks to update the totals.

If the data is not pre-populated I would build a UI that would allow you to add/edit/save rows using JS and run calculations as each box is edited looping through arrays/objects of the data in JS/Angular.

As noted by @Daniel, you should at-least attempt the solution and display it here before asking for the community to write code for you.

Is there not a better way of displaying this information. It seems like you are going about it in a difficult way to start with.

Comment: I've very new to coding so more than likely I am doing it a difficult way.